# Real use case of proptotype scope of spring beans

Tags: spring, theory

Waht is a real example for such kind of stuff? I have already looked through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9664810/spring-prototype-scope-use-cases) post, but the answers to this post seem inconclusive to me. Also there is an advice: *"As a rule, use the prototype scope for all stateful beans and the singleton scope for stateless beans"* - from spring reference, but why do we need our services to be stateful? We can just share this state as a simple dto among services' calls.

Answer (score 0):

One popular use of it is to associate separate instance of a bean to each HTTP session.

Consider your have a bean class called UserConfig. You can set this bean with prototype scope, and configure such that each new HTTP session has its own UserConfig bean instance. (Spring MVC has its own scope called "session" for this purpose, but the concept is similar)

Also the user can change your site configuration, and the changed state is saved on its own instance of the bean (as opposed of altering the global single instance if you set it into singleton scope)

Comment: but there is a session scope for such cases